# Mongock execute range of change-units in integration test

Tags: mongock

**Question**: How can I execute certain range of change-units in integration tests ?

**Example of the problem**: I have three change-units: `X`,`Y`,`Z` (with `order` set to: `1`, `2`, `3`). I have integration tests `T1` for `X`, `Y` and `T2` for `Z`. How can I execute only migrations `X` and `Y` in test `T1` (and "skip" `Z`) ?

**My solution**: I see only two ways.

Assume that each test would have its own runner (like we have in `MongockIntegrationTestBase#mongockBeforeEach`):

1. Each migration file (or a group of files) should be put in one package. And the runner would have `addMigrationScanPackage` specified (to narrow down test to only those migrations that are found in that package). In this case we would have package `P1` with migrations `X` and `Y` and package `P2` with `Z`, so it would be:

   ```
   runnerBuilder.addMigrationScanPackage("P1");
   return runnerBuilder.buildRunner();
   ```
2. Instead of the package, we would use `ChangeUnit#systemVersion` and execute runner with properties: `SystemVersionable#setStartSystemVersion` and `SystemVersionable#setEndSystemVersion`. In this case we would have `systemVersion` in `X`,`Y`,`Z` set to `1`,`2`,`3` and before running the test `T1` we would have:

   ```
   runnerBuilder.setStartSystemVersion("1");
   runnerBuilder.setEndSystemVersion("2");
   return runnerBuilder.buildRunner();
   ```

---

Both solutions are not satisfactory for me.

1. The first one looks weird to create a separate package per migration file
2. The second one is slightly better, but:

- [`SystemVersion` is not intended for that purpose](https://github.com/mongock/mongock/issues/86)
- Ordering `ChangeUnit#order` would have to go in parallel with `ChangeUnit#systemVersion`, and that's not a good approach

Is there any other way I can solve that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird case, as you either want to run the entire migration or performing an unit test only in one change unit, which you can do by just running the method annotated with `@Execution`.

However, a workaround to achieve that is something similar to your first solution. Create your own runner, but instead of passing the package, you can pass the list of classes directly with `addMigrationClasses(List<Class<?>> classes)` or `addMigrationClass(Class<?> clazz)`